# Simple WYSIWYG HTML editor for organize documents

Tags: html, wysiwyg, document, text-editor, codehighlighter

Hi I just need a simple HTML editor, for a school project. What I need is having a folder of wich files can be linked eachone to eachother, that must be viewable in a browser so i tought to HTML (don't know if exists better solutions).

A word file is not what I need because is focused on "single files", while I need focus over multiple files.
A power point file again is not suitable because I need separated files.

Now, spending time writing HTML tags is again not good option. too much time lost focusing on "aspect" rather than "content".

Content manager systems? They are too complex and have a long learning curve, Drupal not good option, that's oriented for website designers.

What I need is a very simple HTML editor with fast learning curve and most basic formatting options:

1. Bould
2. Italic
3. Paragraph
4. hyperlink to another file
5. char size
6. text alignment

and possibly I need few advanced features that would be really usefull:

1. Placing images
2. math formula syntax (even if formula are images that's ok, the important is the ability to edit them easily regardless of what format are they saved.. anything is ok if it is easy to use and is showed correctly at least in Chrome or Firefox)
3. Code snippets (i have to post snippets of code, so I need at least the capability to show code in a different font, and possibly with highlight for syntax)
4. Tables

The folder have not to be posted on a website, so I'll just skip any "server configuration". I just need linked documents, not a website. Isn't there any good and simple WYSIWYG editor out of there wich such features?

A idea was to use a documentation software (like doxygen) the problem is that I have to write special tags and there is no WYSIWIG feature, the only gain is that it will automatically provide code-highlight but this way I lose all other features required.

No online editors please, I need documents on my folder and the ability to zip them on a USB device (if there's no network how can I access online content? Optionaly I would upload them somewhere, but I need to work mainly on my machine)

Comment: Your assomption that "A word file is not what I need because is focused on "single files", while I need focus over multiple files" is erroneous. Word can handle multiple files with links (as LibreOffice/OpenOffice). I said that since relying to a word-processor is the best/unique alternative to your requests (BTW this not seems a programming question so you may be asking in the wrong place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't rely on a wordprocessor here are two HTML+JS WYSIWYG libraries. The code to save the edited files to the folder, however, is up to you (i.e. you cannot completely skip the "server side" part of the problem).

- [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)